# Subquery returning null

Tags: mysql

Got this confusing issue where I need to get data from several tables and join them into one result.

This query was working fine:

```
select simcard.*,customer.name as cuname,mi,ma,co, tot from simcard, customer, 
                (SELECT s.sim_id AS ssim_id, min(datetime) AS mi, max(datetime) AS ma, FLOOR(sum(t.WEIGHT) / 1000) AS tot,
                    (SELECT count(datetime)
                        FROM transactions t 
                        WHERE (t.SIM_ID = ssim_id) AND t.ROWTYPE LIKE '$D' GROUP BY t.sim_id) as co
                        FROM simcard s, transactions t 
                    WHERE (s.sim_id = t.sim_id) AND t.ROWTYPE LIKE '$Z' 
                    AND ( s.customer_id =1 ) GROUP BY s.sim_id) as T
                WHERE (sim_id = ssim_id) AND (simcard.customer_id = customer.id) GROUP BY simcard.SIM_ID
```

But when I add a new customer and new simcard to that customer, it will return empty. I'm guessing this is because there is not transaction with that sim_id in the transaction able.

I've tried to left join but I'm just getting errors.
I've narrowed it down to the first subquery, removing the second one did not result in an non-empty result, but because both subqueries uses the transaction table I'm guessing that both will need some left join.

Structure:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `customer`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `API` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_ID` (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellstruktur `simcard`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `simcard`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `simcard` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SIM_ID` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CUSTOMER_ID` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SCALES_ID` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ACTIVE` char(1) DEFAULT 'N',
  `EMAIL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TARGET_WEIGHT` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LICENSE` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `SIM_ID` (`SIM_ID`),
  KEY `CUSTOMER_ID` (`CUSTOMER_ID`),
  KEY `SCALES_ID` (`SCALES_ID`),
  KEY `SIM_ID_2` (`SIM_ID`,`CUSTOMER_ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Tabellstruktur `transactions`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `transactions`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `transactions` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `SCALES_ID` char(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SIM_ID` char(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROWTYPE` char(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATETIME` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRANSACTIONTIME` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRANSACTIONNUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA0` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA3` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA4` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA5` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA6` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA7` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DATA8` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MEMORY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `MATERIAL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DENSITY` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `VEHICLETYPE` char(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TOOLNAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `WEIGHT` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TRANSACTIONID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `SIM_ID` (`SIM_ID`),
  KEY `TRANSACTIONID` (`TRANSACTIONID`),
  KEY `SCALES_ID` (`SCALES_ID`),
  KEY `SIM_ID_2` (`SIM_ID`,`TRANSACTIONID`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_ROWTYPE` (`ROWTYPE`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_DATETIME` (`DATETIME`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_DATA0` (`DATA0`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_DATA1` (`DATA1`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_DATA2` (`DATA2`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_DATA3` (`DATA3`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_DATA4` (`DATA4`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_DATA5` (`DATA5`),
  KEY `idx_transactions_DATA6` (`DATA6`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
COMMIT;
```

Expected result:

```
ID  SIM_ID          CUSTOMER_ID     SCALES_ID   NAME    ACTIVE  EMAIL   TARGET_WEIGHT   LICENSE cuname              mi                      ma                      co      tot 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
8   10100421287868  1               61          M-61M   Y       NULL    NULL            0       testcustomer        2018-04-26 00:00:00     2018-08-08 00:00:00     14908   529446
```

Comment: It would be useful if you can export the Schema definition of these tables and attach them as well (the `CREATE TABLE` query).

Comment: Schema has been added

Comment: add   a proper data sample and the expected  result

Comment: It has now been added

Comment: your query is invalid. There's no FROM clause in your main statement, unless you have a parenthesis misplaced. Please show the real query

Comment: "co, tot FROM simcard"
Yes there is.
And I just copied the whole statement and testade it on 2 servers running the same database, it worked fine. But it returns null if an subqueries return null.
https://gyazo.com/e65da5dd18b6b55b766ee16191cc700f

Comment: @ThomasG I am missing something? I see 3 SELECT and 3 FROM statements in my query and is also taken directly from working code with no changes.
Only problem is when one of the subqueries returns empty.